# why are the folders i created via 2 different ssh sessions not visible to each other on the same cloud instance in GCP?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm logging into a Google Cloud instance, via:

- SSH from my local machine
- SSH from the cloud console

the local machine username is erjan222 and after SSH shows this:

```
erjan222@instance-1:~$
```

the gcloud username is erjcan and after SSH I see this:

```
erjcan@instance-1:~$
```

I mkdir in both sessions.

I created two folders, names are 'created_from_erjan222', 'created_from_erjcan'.

However when I do ls in either sessions, I should see both but I don't see them!
Each SSH session only can see the folder that I created it on it.

Comment: It looks like you are 2 different users, each in their own home folders. Try typing ```pwd``` in each terminal and see if you're in the same place.

Comment: @DovRine, oh right, i have 2 paths: /home/erjan222 and /home/erjcan, what do i do now? i also need to install docker

Comment: @DovRine, managed to install docker, and uploaded the files I need to run , but can't build using 'docker build' - again permission denied: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: I'm not familiar with gcp, so I can't really help you with docker inside their container, but in linux, your user normally has to be a member of the docker group to use the docker daemon.

Comment: @DovRine, ok, thx  Dov! u still helped me a lot

Comment: What you are seeing is normal. This is user isolation. If you want the users to be able to access each other's files, put them into the same `group`.